# Unity sprite not visible when dragged

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity on a 2D game(I am very amateur on it still) and while using Create->UI->Image to add a new sprite works fine, whenever I drag and drop an image from my assets folder, it always lies behind the background that I have set up for my canvas, regardless of whether i use a higher sort order, if the image is a child of the canvas or the layer is the same for all my canvas elements(UI or default). Also getting the same when attempting to drag an animation.

I was reading somewhere that the canvas is kinda like another UI element and that the image would have to be a child of it in order to display above it, but even when i dragged it as a child to the canvas, I am still getting the same result. Other ideas were about using the world space mode, which appears to be fixing it for the sprite, but I am just not sure on why.

Can somebody explain what is happening ? I wasn't really able to find a good resource that explains it in such a way that would help me understand. Thanks !

Comment: Your questions requires screenshot or access to the project to see what exactly you are doing wrong. I suggest you add screenshot of the background then screenshot of where the child object that is causing the problem is.

Comment: For sprites you shouldn't use "Create->UI->Image". thats for UI elements like the HUD. Use "Game Object -> 2D Object -> Sprite" instead

Answer (score 0):

In screenspace mode, the Canvas always renders on top of the normal scene objects (by design). Dropping types that inherit from UnityEngine.Object (such as sprites) into the Canvas hierarchy do not place them on the screenspace canvas, but rather in the (2D)3D scene (even though they are in the Canvas hierarchy). In order to get an image to adhere to the Canvas visual sorting depth (order in hierarchy), you'd have to place a UnityEngine.UI.Image and then add the resource sprite to it (as you appear to have discovered). At this point you can control the 'depth' of the sprite resource only with respect to other Canvas UI objects and it will always be on top of other scene-based objects.

In other words, the Canvas and its UnityEngine.UI objects (in screenspace mode) will always render on top of your normal scene objects (i.e. like a HUD). In worldspace mode, each Canvas object (and its UnityEngine.UI children) can be positioned in the 3D scene as though it is a normal scene object (more or less).